# How to make class to draw text?

Tags: python, scripting

I want a class `Draw`, inside it a `label(text='Hello World!')` so that I can use it like this

```
draw = Draw()
draw.label(text='Hello World!')
draw.label(text='Demo')
```

Want in such a way that I don't have to set position for all the labels

from https://docs.blender.org/api/current/blf.html#hello-world-text-example

````
import blf
import bpy

font_info = {
    "font_id": 0,
    "handler": None,
}


def init():
    """init function - runs once"""
    import os
    # Create a new font object, use external ttf file.
    font_path = bpy.path.abspath('//Zeyada.ttf')
    # Store the font indice - to use later.
    if os.path.exists(font_path):
        font_info["font_id"] = blf.load(font_path)
    else:
        # Default font.
        font_info["font_id"] = 0

    # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
    font_info["handler"] = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
        draw_callback_px, (None, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')


def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    """Draw on the viewports"""
    # BLF drawing routine
    font_id = font_info["font_id"]
    blf.position(font_id, 2, 100, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
    blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```
````

Comment: So basically, you'd like to be able to call `.label` on the `Draw` class and have it automatically decide where to put the text?

Comment: yes, I want to call `label()` and it should automatically set the position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here's a solution largely based on [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/blf-draw-how-to-automatically-update-3d-view-and-how-to-erase-the-text/1214734/4) answer. I basically encapsulated the functions provided there into a class called Draw. The class has optional parameters allowing you to specify the original positioning of the text, the vertical offset, and the font size, etc.

```
import blf
import bpy


class Draw:
    def __init__(self, original_x=2, original_y=90, y_offset=-50, font_size=50, font_dpi=72):
        self.font_info = {
            "font_id": 0,
            "handler": None,
        }
        self.original_x = original_x
        self.original_y = original_y
        self.current_y = self.original_y
        self.y_offset = y_offset
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.strings_to_draw = []

        """init function - runs once"""
        import os
        # Create a new font object, use external ttf file.
        font_path = bpy.path.abspath('//Zeyada.ttf')
        # Store the font indice - to use later.
        if os.path.exists(font_path):
            self.font_info["font_id"] = blf.load(font_path)
        else:
            # Default font.
            self.font_info["font_id"] = 0

        self.add_handler()

    def label(self, string):
        self.remove_text()
        self.strings_to_draw.append(string)
        self.add_handler()

    def add_handler(self):
        # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
        handler = bpy.app.driver_namespace.get('draw_text')
        if not handler:
            handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
                self.draw_callback_px, (None, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
            dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
            dns['draw_text'] = handler
            self.redraw_regions()

    def draw_callback_px(self, scene, context):
        """Draw on the viewports"""
        # BLF drawing routine
        font_id = self.font_info["font_id"]
        blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
        self.current_y = self.original_y
        for string in self.strings_to_draw:
            blf.position(font_id, self.original_x, self.current_y, 0)
            blf.draw(font_id, string)
            self.current_y += self.y_offset

    def redraw_regions(self):
        for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        region.tag_redraw()

    def remove_text(self):
        handler = bpy.app.driver_namespace.get('draw_text')
        if handler:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(handler, 'WINDOW')
            del bpy.app.driver_namespace['draw_text']
            self.redraw_regions()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    draw = Draw()
    draw.label("Hello!")
    draw.label("Goodbye!")
```

How it works: Whenever label is called, it removes the handler that was previously in place drawing the text every frame. It then adds an additional string to the list of strings that it wants to render. It then adds a new handler that is also aware of the new string.